# Valgrind + C: Handling uninitialized pointers without error

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

Maybe I got too involved with testing my assignment, but here's my dilemma:

This is my offending function (more or less):

```
struct thing{
    char* data;
}

int function(struct thing* arg){
    if(arg->data == NULL)
        return -1; 
}
```

This is my offending input:

```
struct thing *x = malloc(sizeof(struct thing));
function(x);
```

And valgrind outputs this when I test it:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

I'm about 99% sure that this is because valgrind has an issue with evaluating `x->data` when it hasn't been initialized to `NULL` or malloced. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I know that would make the error go away, but my concern is making ````function()```` able to check for unitialized ````x->data```` like in the above case without valgrind printing an error.

Comment: You can't check if data are uninitialized. Uninitialized variables have indeterminate content (or are a trap representation). "indeterminate" = any.

Comment: Your function is also invalid, it's missing an additional `return` statement to cover the other `if` branch.

Answer (score 6):

To my opinion valgrind is right in complaining here because `data` is in fact not initialized and `function` is not able to determine if it was. The function can only check if it has the defined value you used for initialization.

So I would consider using a creation function that does the initialization as well. This way you could also allocate the memory for data right away when passing its size as parameter (or just NULL if you want to do that later).

```
struct thing *newThing(size_t dataSize)
{
   struct thing *t = malloc(sizeof (struct thing));

   if (t)
      t->data = malloc(sizeof(char) * dataSize);
      // or t->data = NULL if it should be done later

   return t;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I guess it can't be helped then. The thing is that my functions get tested with "external" inputs from unit testing and I was worried about that case - but if there's no way of checking for that then I guess it'd be unreasonable to use as input in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a function like this:

```
int function(struct thing *arg) {
    if (arg->data == NULL) {
        // abort here
        return 1;
    } else {
        // use the value here
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here, Valgrind is right about complaining, because it's impossible to achieve the intended behavior for `function()`. If `arg->data` is not explicitly initialized, then its value is indeterminate, and the `if` statement could execute *any* of the two branches depending on whichever random value it reads from `arg->data`.

In general, it's impossible for the function to work correctly, because:

1. If the check `arg->data == NULL` fails, the rest of the code will assume that `arg->data` is not `NULL` and therefore use the invalid value, most likely causing a crash or other kind of problem.
2. If the check `arg->data == NULL` passes, the rest of the code will wrongfully assume that the `data` *is **known** to be invalid*, and do any other kind of thing assuming that `data` was intended to be `NULL`, like for example call some cleanup code at the wrong time.

Other than this, if you really want to be pedantic, reading uninitialized variables is actually *undefined behavior* in C.

The right thing to do in your case is to either use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` or to manually set `x->data = NULL` right after `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocated by malloc is not initialized.

You need to set it to the know state:

```
struct thing *x = calloc(1,sizeof(*x));
```

or

```
struct thing *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
memset(x, 0, sizeof(*x);
```

you can also of course just assign some values to the struct members,

```
struct thing *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
x -> data = NULL;
```